# How do I access TFS Workflow Variables in my Custom Template?

Tags: c#, tfsbuild

I created a [CodeActivity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.activities.codeactivity(v=vs.110).aspx) to be used in a custom TFS Build Template.  The activity has 3 custom InputArguments:

1. TfsBuildProcessTemplatesFolder (...or any relative path I want to build)
2. TfsDropFolder
3. TfsSourceFolder

However, I do not see any familiar TFS variables listed in the list of available Workflow Variables.  I would be willing to "build" the relative paths from a common variable, though.

I am looking for variables to things like:

- $root
- $root\BuildProcessTemplates
- $SourceDir
- $DropFolder

**THE ERROR:**
This tells me I am using the wrong variable(s)

```
Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "BuildDir".
'BuildDir' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

**MY QUESTIONS:**

- Why don't I see familiar TFS variables?
- Do I need to add a reference so the right variables show up in the properties listing?
- Or, am I supposed to use a common object to build the variables?

...things like that.

**THE WORKFLOW VARIABLES IN...**
[image]

**MY CODE:**
In case you need it...

```
namespace Custom.Activities.NuGet
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Activities;
    using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities;
    using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;
    using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Tracking;

    [BuildActivity(HostEnvironmentOption.All)]
    [ActivityTracking(ActivityTrackingOption.ActivityOnly)]
    public sealed class CreateNuGetPackages : CodeActivity
    {
        #region <Properties>

        #region inputs

        public InArgument<string> TfsBuildResourcesFolder { get; set; }
        public InArgument<string> TfsDropFolder { get; set; }
        public InArgument<string> TfsSourceFolder { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #endregion

        #region <Methods>

        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            // Do stuff here
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this TFS 2010 or 2013? The default workflow is quite different between the two. In my TFS 2013 workflow there are variables like `binDirectory` and `srcDirectory` which are defined in the "Compile, Test, and Publish" scope. If you are adding this activity outside that scope, they won't be visible.

Comment: Not sure if unfortunate screenshot buy SourceLocation is not variable but class type

Comment: @drk I was mere trying to show WHERE the variables I am accessing are...not the list itself.  I would be happy to update the image if you wish.  What do you think would be a better highlight for the image?

Comment: I tried creating a variable from within the "Compile, Test and Publish" scope and setting its scope to "Overall"...however...I get the exact same list of variables (not the ones listed by Mike above).  Does anyone have any examples, suggestions on this?

Comment: We are using TFS 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view list of variables available to workflow in one of workflows tabs - variables, optionally arguments tab may be of interest if value is given by your definition config

And as stated by Mike variables are defined in workflow scopes - usually sequences and other block type activities. If the variable your looking for is not seen in the list its not available in currently open/selected scope. You can define your own variable in higher scope and assign value to it for use later in different part.

Intelli-sense for properties should have available variables visible.